# How to return only resolved Promises, ignoring errors, in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, typescript-generics

I have created the function, which should take array of Promises, and return only resolved Promises. Errors must be ignored. So, it seems sth like Promise.all but without errors. The problem is to write the function correctly in typescript. Before, using only JS, I had expected results.

```
function promiseIgnoreErrors<T> (arrayOfPromise: Array<T>)  {
    const isArrayEmpty =
      Array.isArray(arrayOfPromise) && arrayOfPromise.length === 0;
  
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (isArrayEmpty) reject(new Error('Forever pending array'));
  
      let resolvedArray: Array<T> = []
      
      let resolvedCounter: number = 0;
  
      arrayOfPromise.forEach((promise, index) => {
        if (promise instanceof Promise) {
          promise
            .then((data) => {
              resolvedArray[index] = data
              resolvedCounter++;      
              if (arrayOfPromise.length === resolvedCounter) resolve(resolvedArray)   
            })
            .catch(() => {
              resolvedCounter++;
              if (arrayOfPromise.length === resolvedCounter) resolve(resolvedArray)
            })
        } else {
          resolvedArray[index] = promise
          resolvedCounter++;
          if (arrayOfPromise.length === resolvedCounter) resolve(resolvedArray)   
        }
      })
    });
  };
```

Short presentation of the problem. My variables:

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('JS'), 500))
const p2 = 22
const p3 = new Promise((reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Oops')), 100))
const p4 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('TS'), 200))
```

When I have the variables and pass them as array,

```
promiseIgnoreErrors([p1, p2, p3, Promise.reject(10), p4])
```

I would expect:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(3)
// ['JS', 22, 'TS']
```

Now I have:

```
Promise {<pending>}
    [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
    [[PromiseResult]]: Array(5)
    // ['JS', 22, Error: 'Oops, ?, 'TS']
```

You can show my problem in console here:
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wLYwM4FMCSA5mHKrgKKrqrYA8AKgHyIAUAhlWwJ4DywACuix4AXIgCCnLg0YBKRIgDeAKAUKICbFEQ5JqbuQzIoXRAF5VahXu4A6XVPZS+gzDlzyAZJ8Qd9vASF3WwAbXDBCKAALczMzRAAGAG5LSwUyKBBUJDBcAHdEV2FcFhYybDgQgDdcABpEMgArXGh5M2YVKwUYYFYHf0NjLnkmlqgWXILKahYAcgAxUlwa1BRwgBMYCN8pWdlZFIU0tTDtcsqa9ZsuMWuZc0QAbQBdY6OuxFOG3Arq3HWAMJwcBQXCoMRgEAYABGYIeyVSHz83BcQTwtmApHIbAgUVKaDceHqW3WuAAHm0Om81D1WATijowFo2JBcHBekV3PJOh81PT3NSPrZouFSus2FA2JSlILeec-lcpI8SeTng9xZLZR95ZcgSCwQBqA1JD5arq0pz+VGE3ChcKRGJxeI6-56sCg1AjH4XEouxX+eTvXlWAC+sjNClsEAluNK0p5wasfrdHqNh0TVgtyICnPRYQi0Vizu9CpTYK9vxqZRLl2u4YzCjDspDiFwITwMozfuuyrApLJavi-LwZuTwPdhuNZqzzkCNrtBcdcW+ldd449FZ91dX-u4gcQzepTdDB0sIZSyg0TO0yAAjA9JoU0SVtz7pXgoPQYBg2SBxixpRdOYACkAGU9nqABWBIEn2S9NBvAAmB5EMQ+DrxQABmB98ifG1SlGVpzGYD8vx-YF-0A3BmmgCZcOmUg5h4OBkGwPZZHqW8YLgq8tBQAAWB5c1tQjxi48NeJvSCcIKYSCJrDxiMQUjv1-SilKA2Z6HAjjEEQ7jw3Q35bRCOBCBYYcCGIJYGJoFhHjvepkEQpzMKc-inMg559iAA)

I think the problem is generic type here and exactly this line:

```
let resolvedArray: Array<T> = []
```

because it indicates that the returned table must consist of the same elements as in the input. And maybe it should similar to:

```
let resolvedArray: Array<K> extends T = []
```

Of course I know the line above is wrong, but maybe i should follow this idea.. Or maybe my function is not OK?

Please about any help!

Comment: The types have no impact on what happens at runtime, if you're getting the wrong output the *code* is wrong.

Comment: `reject(new Error('Forever pending array'));` definitely does look like an error to me. But really, why are you even writing this yourself instead of using `Promise.allSettled`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I got it. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: One problem in your code is that `new Promise((reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Oops')), 100))` is exactly equivalent to `new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(new Error('Oops')), 100))`. You probably meant to use `new Promise((resolve, reject) => …)`.

Comment: @Bergi I have noticed it. The problem appears when I am testing my code. Then when I have `new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Oops')), 100))` typescript is yelling at me because I don't use 'resolve'.. and my test fails automatically.

Comment: @karolina-szlenk If it's just a warning about unused variables, you normally can write `(_resolve, reject) => …`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be enough.

The idea is that `ERRORED` is a sentinel object; if a promise in the array throws, we catch that and transmute it into an `ERRORED`.

`isNotErrored(x)` is a type guard function that guarantees TypeScript that `x` isn't the sentinel, so the type of `results.filter(isNotErrored)` ends up being `T[]`, not `(T | '__ERRORED__')[]`.

```
const ERRORED = '__ERRORED__';
type ErroredType = typeof ERRORED;

function isNotErrored<T>(x: T | ErroredType): x is T {
  return x !== ERRORED;
}

async function promiseIgnoreErrors<T>(promises: Array<Promise<T>>): Promise<Array<T>> {
  const results = await Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(() => ERRORED as ErroredType)));
  return results.filter(isNotErrored);
}
```

E.g.

```
promiseIgnoreErrors([Promise.resolve(8), Promise.reject("oh no"), Promise.resolve(16)]).then(r => {
  console.log(r);
});
```

logs

```
[8, 16]
```

ignoring the rejection.

## EDIT:

For the original inputs

```
const p1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('JS'), 500))
const p2 = 22
const p3 = new Promise((reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Oops')), 100))
const p4 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('TS'), 200))
```

this won't type-check, since not all inputs are promises, and that's IMHO the correct behavior. As discussed in the comments, bare values should be wrapped with `Promise.resolve()`, i.e.

```
const p2 = Promise.resolve(22)
```

or you could do that internally:

```
function isPromiseLike<T>(x: T | Promise<T>): x is Promise<T> {
  return (x as any).then;  // Checks whether the object has a `then`; should be mostly enough.
}

async function promiseIgnoreErrors2<T>(values: Array<T | Promise<T>>): Promise<Array<T>> {
  const promises = values.map((v) => isPromiseLike(v) ? v : Promise.resolve(v));
  const results = await Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(() => ERRORED as ErroredType)));
  return results.filter(isNotErrored);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use a symbol or an object here that have a unique identity, not a string literal.

Comment: @karolina-szlenk What did or didn't it do in your case?

Comment: @Bergi Do symbols have an unique type identity to use for something like `type ErroredType`?

Comment: @AKX No idea. Getting typescript to accept working code is always an afterthought for me, making it work correctly has first priority…

Comment: @karolina-szlenk I tested this in the Typescript playground; seems to work fine.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, `typeof Symbol("foo")` is just `Symbol`, so it's not unique as far as the type system is concerned. A constant string is unique though, so while Symbols would be ES2015 sound, constant strings are TS sound...

Comment: You have not considered `const p2 = 22` in your answer, so following does not compile
`promiseIgnoreErrors1([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5])`

Comment: @PritamKadam OP says "which should take array of Promises" – this is what this does. If they need to mix and match bare values in with promises, they can wrap them (`Promise.resolve(x)`) before passing them in here.

Comment: @Bergi yep I mean the same as Pritam Kadam has written. The problem is with another value like number, object and so on.

Comment: I added an edit that takes care of internally wrapping bare values into promises.

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function promiseIgnoreErrors<T>(arrayOfPromise: Array<T>) {
  const promises = await Promise.all(arrayOfPromise.map((p) => promisify(p)))
  return promises.filter((v) => v != null)
}

const promisify = <T>(value: T) =>
  Promise.resolve(value)
    .then((v) => (v instanceof Error ? null : v))
    .catch(() => null)


const r = promiseIgnoreErrors([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5])

console.log(r)                // Promise { <pending> }
r.then((x) => console.log(x)) // [ 'JS', 22, 'TS' ]
```

**Update**

Removed flatMap version to avoid confusion

Comment: There's really no good reason to use `flatMap` instead of `filter` here

Comment: I have both the variations, flatMap will do it in one pass, filter ll require two passes

Comment: Uh, no? Where would the second pass come from?

Comment: oh you are right, I thought I got rid of map but obviously I did not ;)

Comment: Here's hoping `null` isn't a valid result for any of the promises though...

Comment: I did not get your point, I have used null to represent failed promise like `Promise<Option<T>>` as you have used ERRORED

Here `promisify` function returns `Promise<T | null>` which means promise ll never fail, it ll always resolve with T or null

Comment: If a promise would successfully resolve with `null` as the value, it would be removed by this.

Comment: sorry, still not getting your point, are you saying something is fundamentally wrong above?

I see this as follows:
Lest say you are designing `findCustomer` API, then I would say it's one of the valid/correct return type would be `Promise<Customer | null>`

Comment: @PritamKadam A `findCustomerById` API is a good example. What if it threw an error for malformed customer IDs, and returned `null` for customers that don't exist? Your code would consider the nulls as errors too and return an empty list.

Comment: I dont see why malformed URL would return null, and if theres multiple failures possible then I would model my api to capture those like `Promise<Either<ErrorAdt, Option<Customer>>>`

Here Option<Customer> represent Customer | null, both of these represent success.
Rest of the failures goes to left side of either and represented by ADT.

This is very common and proven pattern in scala and in general in FP if you search error handling techniques